# jquery how to replace all strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string in javascript, for example : "i have two PC and two laptops";
and result should be "i have three PC and three laptop".

So, I want to change all occurrences of word "two" to "three"

Comment: Plain JavaScript is enough to do this. But show us some of your effort.

Comment: You don't need jquery for this. Use a simple replace (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Please use a javascript reference before asking a question

Comment: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @UnknownFury don't need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new_string = 'pop'.replace(/two/g,'three')

this will change 'two' with 'three'

Comment: It is simple javascript, you don't need jQuery for it

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain, replacng more then one occurence can be done with replace and a regular expression.

```
var input = "i have two PC and two laptops";
var output = input.replace(/two/g, "three");
```

Comment: You need plain JS for this. You can use JQuery to find and update DOM element with this text though:)

Answer (score 0):

This will get them all:

```
function replace(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}


var str = 'i have two PC and two laptops';
var find = 'two';
var replace = 'three'

alert(replaceAll(find,replace,str));
```